# Pascal writeln Задом наперед

Tags: pascal

Вот есть такая программа:

```
var n,c:integer; 
begin
  readln(n);
  while (n div 2 > 0) do begin
    c:=n mod 2; 
    n:=n div 2;
    write(c,' ');
  end;
  write(1);
end.
```

Мне надо, чтобы выводило задом наперед.
Но лучше без использования массивов.

Comment: а что делает-то программа?

Comment: Переводит из десятичной в двоичную...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конвертировать в двоичное представление можно гораздо проще:

```
for с := 31 downto 0 do
    Write((n shr с) and 1);
```

Если нужно обрезать лишние нули слева, то можно так, например:

```
l := 0;
repeat
  l := l + 1;
  if (n shr l) = 0 then Break;
until l = 32;
for c := l - 1 downto 0 do
  Write((n shr c) and 1);
```

Comment: Второй способ некорректный: нельзя использовать переменную цикла после него, ее значение неопределено.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Вроде бы в Паскале классический цикл, и значение переменной цикла гарантированно «правильное» после цикла (то есть, равно значению на _последней_ итерации, как бы цикл не завершился). (Но я не уверен.)

Comment: @VladD нет, там *unspecified behavior*. ЕМНИП, Turbo и Borland Pascal делают как вы написали, Delphi 7.0 оставляет следующее значение (плюс кидает предупреждение). Ну и, кажется, циклы `to` и `downto` могут вести себя по-разному.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Значит, пожертвовали красотой ради эффективности, жаль. (Я и правда после 7-го Турбо Паскаля с новыми версиями не работал.)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, спасибо, я и не знал этой особенности (в fpc всё работало нормально). Ответ исправил. Пока исправлял, в старом варианте ещё один косячок нашёл - при n = 0 не выводилось вообще ничего.

Answer (score 4):

добавляй c к Своей строке и выводи Строку после цикла:

```
var s:string;
s = c + s;
```